# how to display factor id on plot axis and factor id and value in legend?

Tags: r

I have a plot where the `request` is a factor with long values so they don't display on the char axis.

```
 plot( time_taken ~ request )
```

The data in this case looks like:

```
   time_taken              request
1           7 /servlet1/endpoint2/
2           2            /session/
3          10 /servlet1/endpoint3/
4           2 /servlet1/endpoint2/
5           8 /servlet4/endpoint2/
6           5            /session/
...
```

**Question:** Is there a way to plot something like the factor level id on the x axis, and the factor level id + factor full string in the legend?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal set of data, perhaps `dput(head(dat, n=20))`?

Comment: Just to make sure: does `plot( time_taken ~ request_type, las = 2 )` or `plot( time_taken ~ request_type, las = 3 )` help you?

Comment: I've renamed `request_type` to `request` in the question, but `las=2` or `3` does not help because the factor values are quite long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question generates a boxplot, so I assume that's what you want. Here are four ways to go about it.

This will generate a boxplot with the x-axis numbered, and the full names in the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=as.integer(request),y=time_taken, color=request))+
  labs(x="request")
```

[image]

As you can see below, though, with ggplot the labels are discernible (at least in the example).

```
ggp <- ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=request,y=time_taken))
ggp
```

[image]

In a situation like this I'd be inclined to rotate the plot.

```
ggp + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Finally, here's a way in base R, although IMO it's the least appealing option.

```
plot(time_taken~factor(as.integer(request)),df, xlab="request")
labs <- with(df,paste(as.integer(sort(unique(request))),sort(unique(request)),sep=" - "))
legend("topright",legend=labs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution uses `ggplot2`. Following an example with some sample data.

```
df <- data.frame(factor = c("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 
                        "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
                        "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"),

             time = c(5, 7, 9))

library(ggplot2)
qplot(data = df, factor, time) + scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)
```

You can also use directly the function `abbreviate` on your factor  levels in your data frame, so that you can work with abbreviated labels, also avoiding `ggplot2`, if you're not familiar with it.
Look at `?abbreviate`